# Include the table name in a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I need to include the table name in a SELECT statement, together with some columns and the unique identifier of the table.

I don't know if there is possible to take the table name from a select within that table or some kind of unique identifier.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you're querying a table then you already know the name of that table. You can add it as a string...

Comment: P.S. can you remove either Oracle or MySQL (they're separate database systems) unless you're using both RDBMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thank you for your responses but I fixed this in this way (it was too easy actually)

```
select 'table1' as tableName, col1, col2 from anyTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to query the system catalog of the database to find the primary key and all unique constraints of the table, then choose one that best suites your needs. You can expect to find 0, 1, or more such constraints.

For an Oracle database you'd use something like

```
  select 
   c.constraint_name,
   col.column_name
  from
   dba_constrants c,
   dba_cons_columns col
  where
   c.table_name = 'YOURTABLE'
   and c.constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
   and c.constraint_name = col.constraint_name
  order by
   c.constraint_name, 
   col.position
```

For MySQL you would query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE views in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you all the table names from your database, you can tweak it as you see fit

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: And how does that answer the question of the unique identifier?

Comment: thanks but I want to get the name of the table when I am performing a select within that table